# Current day and month (dd/mm) by counting number of days since January 1

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Please does anyone have an idea on how to calculate current date (only dd/mm) by counting the number of days since the 1st January?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?  I know the current date, so why does it need to be calculated?

Comment: For example, in 2016, 157 days will be 6th June

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add 157 to the first day of the year:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + 157 from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')+157
-------------------------
2016-06-06
```

The `trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')` part gives you the first day of the year. You can also use a fixed date:

```
select date '2016-01-01' + 157 from dual;

DATE'2016-01-01'+157
--------------------
2016-06-06
```

And you can use an interval rather than a plain number of days if you prefer:

```
select date '2016-01-01' + numtodsinterval(157, 'DAY') from dual;

DATE'2016-01-01'+NUMTODSINTERVAL(157,'DAY')
-------------------------------------------
2016-06-06
```

[Read more about datetime/interval arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208).

Either way of you only want DD/MM then use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(date '2016-01-01' + 157, 'DD/mM') from dual;

TO_CH
-----
06/06
```